# Service Bus Queue Retry strategy : WCF application is timing out because of long retries

Tags: azure-queues

We have one service which puts data in service bus queue. We have retry strategy implemented for this. But as per Windows Azure team, queue can go down for 1-3 minutes. So we should have retry strategy which should try more than 3 minutes.

If we will retry for 3 minutes than the client which is waiting for response will time out as default time out is 60 seconds. If we will increase the timeout then customer has to wait for 3 minutes in case of outage.

What is the best way to implement this scenario?

```
a. Should we keep client waiting? which will not be good experience for Client.

b. Should we keep timeout same , but then client will retry and we will have duplicate records?
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Its a general scenario and one of the basic rule which needs to be followed is that any client shouldn't be allowed to wait.

So as per my understanding and suggestion what you can do is:
1. Check if there is a request in Queue.
2. If 1 is true don't retry
3. If 1 is false retry

Also timeout would be a good exception that can be thrown to client or any user friendly message (you will need a new approach for that).

Point is client should know everything, if he is waiting or if he is out of queue or if he is in queue, then only you can create Robust and User friendly application